# how to find button to click in Selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, button

```
</div>
<fieldset class="pi-search-form__footer">
<div class="pi-search-form__footer-cta" data-ng-show="stay.isStandardBooking()">
<button class="btn btn--primary" data-ng-click="submitSearch()">
<span data-ng-switch="ctaText">
<span data-ng-switch-when="checkavailability">Check availability</span>
<span data-ng-switch-when="searchnow">Search now</span>
<span data-ng-switch-default data-pi-track-click="SEARCH_AGAIN">Search</span>
</span>
</button>
</div>
```

This is my button code and I want to click "Check availability" button.
I use that code but it not works.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Check availability')]")
```

Comment: What error message you are getting? Also try this xpath once- //div[@class='pi-search-form__footer-cta']//span[contains(text(), 'Check availability')]

Comment: do no jump to automation without having basic knowledge of programming.  Read python and selenium API first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As you want to click on a button so your `xpath` should be unique and should identify a single element. Hence instead of `find_elements_by_xpath` you should consider using `find_element_by_xpath`. To click on the **`Check availability`** button you can use the following line of code:

```
//ensure the imports
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
//other code
//click on Check availability button
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn--primary']//span[@data-ng-switch-when='checkavailability']")))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn--primary']//span[@data-ng-switch-when='checkavailability']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: It returns 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click''

Comment: it returns -'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'. I think when click button page not loaded or may be cookies problem. So please help me .

Comment: It clicked but not go to next page. So please let me know ?

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Check availability')]")
```

and if it's not working use explicit wait.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
checkAvailability = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(text(), 'Check availability')]")))
```

Comment: I used that also but not work - browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Check availability')]")

Comment: you can click the element by using the click() method `browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Check availability')]").click()`